# update method does not work/will not display in datagridview

Tags: c#, database, sql-update

I am trying to calculate an average and then store the average in the database. I have a **datagridview** which is *bound to the database*. I created an *update method* **UpdateAvgSkill** which *uses the primary key* to update the average.

If my update method is working correctly, the **results should be displayed in my datagridview**. however this does not happen. Below is the code I am using to update the average.

```
playerListTableAdapter.UpdateAvgSkill(
           Convert.ToDecimal(average), 
           Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPlayers.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value));
playerListTableAdapter.Update(dsPlayerTeam.PlayerList);
```

Is there some other way which I should be using to get the database to update itself? Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the database updated correctly?  Is it just a matter of binding the new data back to the `DataGridView`?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have another datagridview bound to a filtered subset of the same database table, and when I manually change the AverageSkill in dgvPlayers, the other dataGridViews update with the new data, so the database binding appears to be correct. Also, I can see other columns update based on drag and drop functions in another tab.

Comment: As your dataGridView updates when you change your data manually I think there may be a problem with playerListTableAdapter.UpdateAvgSkill(...) Try to print out Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPlayers.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)) right before calling UpdateAvgSkill and check if this is the correct value

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time debugging the **UpdageAvgSkill()** method in the code, we were able to confirm that the values from the datagridview we were using to calculate the Average skill weren't being committed to the database prior to our running the method, so it was running against null values.

The problem is really about getting the new cell values to commit to the database before trying to update the average skill as discussed in this question:

[Commiting changes in DataGridView before Row Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203320/commiting-changes-in-datagridview-before-row-change)

Thank you for your help.