# Commiting changes in DataGridView before Row Change

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

We're working with a DataGridView bound to a database. We are trying to have one of the columns calculated as an average of some of the other columns from the database.

1. - We were unable to create a computed column in the database nor were we successful in creating one in the dataset. If there's a way to do this, our problem is solved.

Ex: AvgSkill = Avg(Skill1, Skill2, Skill3)

1. Since we can't seem to create a computed column, we tried creating a cell event handler that would calculate the new average and then update the database with the new information, however as soon as we change a cell, and try to update the database, we lose all the data we added to that row.

We've figured out that the dataGridView only updates the bound data source when you leave the row, so when we try to do an update, it erases anything entered in that row.

Is there a way to force the datagridview to update the bound data source in our event handler before we leave the row? Updating the tableadapter doesn't seem to do it.

thanks in advance for any help :)

-Dominique

Comment: Why are you not able to calculate the average in the database?  This seems like an inefficient workaround when you *should* be able to do all the work in the database.  What type of DB is it?

Comment: The simple solution is only possible if you are ready to make your datagridview unbound and bing it at formalod or in constructor. That can also be guided.

Comment: @TrueDevelopment The database is a SQL server compact database.

Comment: @Sami Unbinding the datagridview seems like it would be a lot of work at this point, but willing to consider it, but I'm not sure how I would manually load the data into the dgv and manually udpdate the db when data changes in the dgv.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried in SQL?  I really think that is a better way to go.  You couldn't use `AVG(ColumnName)`?  Or possibly something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268760/how-do-i-select-avg-of-multiple-columns-on-a-single-row

Comment: You can work with `DataColumn.Expression` and build a `DataView` that would always be new assigned to the `DataGridView`, if the user changed something in the Rows. Reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @TrueDevelopment What we tried as an expression for a computed field was:

Avg(Skill1, Skill2, Skill3, Skill4)

however, that didn't work as I believe Avg can only be used on data collections from a Join. I might be missing something though.

Comment: My apologies, but I still don't quite understand what you are trying to do.  Are "Skill1", "Skill2", etc columns or rows?  Is this not an accurate representation of what you are trying to accomplish...  `SELECT ((s1 + s2 + s3) / 3) AS AverageSkill FROM TableName`?

Comment: @TrueDevelopment - Skill1, Skill2 and Skill3 are columns in the table. I will try your SELECT statement, however I think it will give inaccurate values if some of the columns are null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do the following in the cell change event handler:

```
    private void dgvPlayers_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         this.Validate();
    }
```

Forces the validation of the DataGridView with every cell change. You could limit this action to specific columns by checking e.ColumnIndex. You could also include any code required to make calculations at the same time.

;)